# Please help me get rid of asmonitor.exe

Tags: windows, virus, malware, keylogger, malware-removal

It might be silly and I trully apologize if the question is not apropriate here, but I have really tried and got to nowhere. I have a windows xp startup error which indicates something about asmonitor.exe program from the ActualSpy keylogger. I had installed but removed ActualSpy keylogger using Superantispyware or something close. I have searched the registries and found a asmonitor entry deleted. I looked at startup programs and can not find the asmonitor program. In addition, I searched the c: drive using regular explorer search and searched using ESET NOD32 antivirus. In each case I cannot find the application...
I have even looked at startup programs using msinfo32 command.
msconfig->startup
NOTHING! it drives me crazy! I can't get rid of it. it is still showing up at windows startup!
Where do I find this little program? where is it located? I don't want it to keep showing up. I don't want programs that can do it.. or maybe free ones. But I prefer manual solutions. aren't are any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a manual solution, you should check the registry for the offending file itself, or check the "run-on-startup" locations for suspicious files (in case it's not launching directly from asmonitor.exe).  These can include:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

There may be more as well, depending on your system configuration.  I usually do a search for "RunOnce" and check all the keys that show up around each occurrence that it finds.

Personally, for changing the startup options, I prefer to use the [Startup Control Panel](http://www.mlin.net/StartupCPL.shtml) program.  It's free, stand-alone (no installer necessary) and it checks all the main areas that a program could start from and allows you to disable or delete them.

You mentioned having already looked at MSConfig, but you can also double check if it is running as a service by launching `Services.msc` from the run window.  If it is there, you can set it to disabled to prevent it from running.

Comment: +1 when i'll be able to vote because I have searched the entire registry for asmonitor.exe and didn't found it, but I haven't thought about it running as a service, man.. k, I'll give it a try when I get home. thank you.

Comment: WEll did try all your advices but still no solution to the problem.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running?

Comment: windows xp os version

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is to see if you have a legacy `AUTOEXEC.BAT` file that may be running it.  Perhaps you could do a text search of your hard drive for the `asmonitor.exe` to see if it is being launched by any other batch or script files.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably still in the Run section of your registry. Start regedit and look in:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce and
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
```

There's probably an entry for asmonitor.exe in there, which you can remove.

If that's not it, then there's probably *another* program running that is adding asmonitor.exe back in again.

**NOTE:** *The usual warnings about changing your registry directly apply - the registry is at the core of Windows and inadvertently changing the wrong thing can leave your application or Windows setup unusable*

Comment: It might be helpful, for the sake of newer users, to specify what the 'usual warnings' are anyway...:)